# Быстрая переписка

Tags: архитектура

Добрый день хотел узнать как реализуются программы на подобие (агент, мсн..) то есть мгновенная переписка, сохраняются ли где то сообщения?

Answer (score 1):

Я видел 3 варианта:
 1. Не хранятся на сервере вообще
 2. Хранятся до момента прочтения
 3. Хранятся всегда

Вариант 1:

Персонажи:
 1. Пользователь **П**
 2. Программа-клиент **А**
 3. Программа-клиент **Б**
 4. Сервер **С**
Прим: **П** пользуется **А**.

Сценарий:
1. **П** написал сообщение для **Б**
2. **П** говорит **А**: передай сообщение **Б**
3. **А** сохраняет у себя сообщение
4. **А** говорит **C**: передай сообщение **Б**
5. Если **C** отвечает - Передал, то **А** удаляет свою копию
6. Если **С** отвечает - **Не** передал, то ( например ) через 1 час **А** повторяет пункт 4

Comment: а сохранять сообшения не замедлит процесс и ещё можете поделиться ссылкой или написать про 1-й вариант

Comment: Если ответ вам помог - проголосуйте ( слева - пальчик вверх )<br>
Если это лучший ответ на вопрос - отметьте его ( слева - галочка )<br>
Желательно это сделать со всеми заданными вопросами!